# How to check how the web resource is requested?

Tags: php, web

Using PHP, is there a way to check for certain how a web server resource is requested while minimising room for forging and hacking? Or in simpler terms, how to check whether it is a hyperlink click, direct URL, submission of HTML Form, programmatic access etc.?

What about if tools other than PHP is used?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't make that bullet proof that way, but a good start is `$_SERVER`.

For example with `$_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']` you can determine if the request was `get/post/put/...`

Regarding link click or direct access: `$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']` might help.

At last `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']` might hold some useable info, to determine if the script was run over an webserver (like apache) or the console.

Please see the [documentation](http://www.php.net/manual/de/reserved.variables.server.php) for more info on that.

And as I mentioned before: **You can't be sure of anything here**, but if you just want some info, and not use it for security reasons, you are fine.

If you want security you need to look into the possibilities with .htaccess.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you might be alluding to [cross-site request forgery (CSRF)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-site_request_forgery) attacks. CSRF attacks are where an attacker can cause a request to a site that appears to come from a legitimate user (e.g. "Transfer $500 to account 1234."). These attacks abuse the trust that a website has in the visitor. The request might appear legitimate because it is accompanied by a session cookie that matches the user's authentication session.

To prevent CSRF attacks, developers usually add hidden form fields that have "CSRF tokens." This token is submitted with the form submission. It is a means of ensuring form submissions are legitimate. Upon submission, the CSRF token is verified (it is usually compared to the token value stored or computed on the server).

For information on implementation details, check out [OWASP](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Cross-Site_Request_Forgery_%28CSRF%29_Prevention_Cheat_Sheet). One important note is not to expose tokens in the URL (i.e. through GET requests) as these can expose tokens to potential attackers.

If you have concerns beyond CSRF, please feel free to update your question and I'd be happy to provide additional information that is more specific to your needs.